# JTAG scan chain interrogation fails

Tags: hardware, jtag, openocd

I am currently trying to get my Bus Blaster v4.1a to work. I want to use openocd to communicate with a device over JTAG. The device that I want to communicate with is a Qualcomm_qca4531.

First of all let me show you the command that I enter in the terminal just in case that I am already doing something wrong here:

```
~/openocd/tcl$ sudo openocd -f interface/ftdi/dp_busblaster.cfg -f target/qualcomm_qca4531.cfg
```

The 2 config files that I am using were already provided by openocd and can be found here: 
https://github.com/analogdevicesinc/openocd/blob/master/tcl/interface/ftdi/dp_busblaster.cfg 
https://github.com/ntfreak/openocd/blob/master/tcl/target/qualcomm_qca4531.cfg

The error that I am receiving from OpenOCD right after entering the command is the following.

```
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0+dev-00936-g0a13ca1a (2019-10-10-09:36)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : If you need SWD support, flash KT-Link buffer from https://github.com/bharrisau/busblaster
and use dp_busblaster_kt-link.cfg instead
adapter speed: 2000 kHz

Info : auto-selecting first available session transport "jtag". To override use 'transport select <transport>'.
qca4531_ddr2_550_550_init
Info : Listening on port 6666 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 4444 for telnet connections
Info : clock speed 2000 kHz
Error: JTAG scan chain interrogation failed: all zeroes
Error: Check JTAG interface, timings, target power, etc.
Error: Trying to use configured scan chain anyway...
Error: qca4531.cpu: IR capture error; saw 0x00 not 0x01
Warn : Bypassing JTAG setup events due to errors
Info : Listening on port 3333 for gdb connections
```

I already checked a few things:
I checked if any of the JTAG Pins is shortened to gnd or vcc. They aren't. 
I also tried to use urJTAG to communicate with the device, it doesn't work either but I receive a different error: TDO seems to be stucked at 1. 
I also checked if I connected the right pins. I have 6 pins that I have to connect. VCC, GND, TMS, TCK, TDI and TDO. There are only these 4 JTAG pins on the board but after a little research I found out that I only need these 4 pins, TRST and other JTAG pins are optional so I think there should be everything fine with the connection.
I can also confirm that the Bus Blaster supports the same voltage levels as my target device. (3.3V)

Can you think of any other reason why I get the error mentioned above?
Is it possible that JTAG is deactivated on the target device? I tried to find out what openocd output looks like when JTAG is deactivated but I can't find anything helpfull.

Thanks to everyone in advance.

Comment: What I can read "OpenOCD will only work with the libUSB drivers"
Might be worth checking ?
Worth a read - http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/Bus_Blaster_OpenOCD_guide

Comment: If the device *has* a TRST connection (it is optional in the spec but is often implemented) then you will need to drive that pin (I do not know if your device actually implements TRST)

Comment: @Sorenp I will check that out.

Comment: @PeterSmith The device does not have a TRST connection. It only has the 4 pins (TDI, TDO, TMS and TCK) for the JTAG connection. I checked that in the datasheet.

Comment: @Sorenp 
Edit: I checked it out because I was not sure if I have installed libUSB but I had. So that shouldn't be the cause of the problem

Comment: Okay @Ramazuri hope you can figure out the problem good luck.

Comment: When I I have had JTAG chain issues in the past (particularly at the identification stage) my first attempt to fix it is to slow the interface speed down. I would try it at 1MHz; that may or may not fix the issue but it is a fairly common problem.

Comment: @PeterSmith Unfortunately it didn't fix the issue but that is a usefull information, I will keep it in mind for the future. Thank you.